# Is there any way to cancel iOS InAppPurchase from my website?

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, auto-renewable

I am implementing AutoRenewal InAppPurchase first time in my iOS app. I know we can cancel the auto renewal from iTunesStore in iPhone settings. But I want to know if we can cancel the auto renewal from other platforms (like my website or android version of the same app).

How can I find the correct answer for this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no. Subscriptions can only be managed by the Apple account that made the purchase.